# Hide widget if user is logged in without plugin

Tags: widgets

I would like to be able to hide a widget in the front-end if the user is logged in and only display the widget when the user is not logged in.

I have found a plugin that does this called Widget Logic however i don't want to install too many plugins especially for something as small as this.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comfortable changing the code where the widget is outputted you could use the [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function. Something like this:

```
<div id="widget_area">
    <?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // show nothing
        } else {
            dynamic_sidebar('widget_name');
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The downside being that this is now hard coded and you might have to add this function in a few different files.

Steve